# Чтение и запись файла блоками Delphi

Tags: delphi, файлы, byte

Пытаюсь прочитать у файла, к примеру, первые 17 байтов, а потом их записать обратно, но возникают вопросы. Делаю так:

```
 AssignFile(f, 'C:\Project1.exe');
  Reset(f, 1);
  while not Eof(f) do
    begin
      BlockRead(f, AByte, 17);
    // тут чтот делаю с AByte 
    end;
  CloseFile(f);
```

Как теперь записать обратно `AByte`, заменив при этом только те байты, которые я прочитал. Например :

Есть файл с байтами: `0 2 12 13 25 26 98`

Читаю первые 3 байта: `0 2 12`

Увеличиваю их на единицу: `1 3 13`

Теперь записываю их обратно: `1 3 13 13 25 26 98` -- вот тут и загвоздка, не могли ли бы вы помочь мне с этим ?

Comment: Не понятно в чём загвоздка. Пишите BlockWrite и всё. Если записать с смещением ноль, делаете Seek или както-Seek функцию.

Comment: тобишь, так : seek(f,0); BlockWrite(f, AByte, 17); 
?

Comment: и так он заменит первые 17 байтов  ? или просто допишет вперед их ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Открыть файл в режиме чтение-запись `FileMode :=2;`
2. Запомнить позицию в файле. Используйте `FPos := Filepos(f)`
3. Отредактировать то что вам нужно в `AByte`
4. Вернуться при помощи `Seek(f, FPos)` на эту позицию
5. `BlockWrite(f, AByte, 17);`

Comment: Я немног запутался, поможете разобраться ? по сути, щас цикл while не нужен. да ? тобишь, будет так :
` AssignFile(f, 'C:\Project1.exe');
  Reset(f, 2);

      BlockRead(f, AByte, 17);
        FPos := Filepos(f);
    seek(f,FPos);
    BlockWrite(f, AByte, 17);
  CloseFile(f);`
подправьте, если не так

Comment: Да.while не нужен, если нет цикла. Смысл в том, что Вы после обработки возвращаетесь на ту же позицию откуда были прочитаны данные, чтобы записать обработанные данные. Но для этого позицию внутри файла нужно запомнить. Если цикла нет и Вы меняете первые 17 байт, то делать Filepos не обязательно, просто перейти на нулевую позицию seek(f, 0);

Comment: спасибо, работает, только не подскажите, почему выскакивает ошибка acces volation at address 0B0A0908. Read of address 0B0A0908 

при этом ни на одну строку не показывает

Comment: Всё зависит от того какой тип у abyte. Вообще в отладчике нужно пошагово пройти F7-F8, посмотреть что в abyte пишется, все ли нормально там.

Comment: Ну и посмотреть на чем именно AV вылетает.

Comment: тип стоит byte   AByte: array[1..17] of byte; 
хм, странно, у меня стоял массив от 1 до 8 и вылетала вышеперечисленная ошибка, поставил до 17 и теперь вылетает ошибка Read beyond end of file на строке  BlockRead(f, AByte, 17); даж если увеличиваю массив, все равно ошибка

Comment: Можно попробовать seek(f, 0) написать перед blockread. Возможно он так открывает файл и перемещает файловый указатель на конец.По идее должно быть прочитано 17 байт, если есть какой-нибудь hex редактор в нем бы сравнить эти байты с тем, что прочитано...

Comment: когда у меня стоял массив до 8, то я сравнивал с hex редактором и прога читала правильно, щас же не могу, ибо не успевает прога считать ошибку бьет. Попробую сик выше добавить

Comment: добавил   seek(f,0); выше blockread, но все так же ((( 
мой конечный код выглядит так :
 AssignFile(f, 'C:\Project2.exe');
  Reset(f, 2);
         seek(f,0);
      BlockRead(f, AByte, 17);

     for i:= 0 to 17 do begin
     memo2.Lines.Add(IntToStr(AByte[i]));
     AByte[i]:=AByte[i]+1;
     end;

    seek(f,0);
    BlockWrite(f, AByte, 17);
  CloseFile(f);


end;

Comment: Странно, можно посмотреть еще чему равен размер файла FileSize(f) (в переменную его присвоить и посмотреть в отладчике); короче говоря промониторить переменные : позицию файла, размер, потом уже чтение сделать. Вроде бы все должно работать.Read beyond end of file - чтение сквозь конец файла ж переводится. То есть два варианта, либо файл короткий (меньше 17 байт), либо мы на конце стоим (читаем 17 байт, а до конца 8, например)... что-то другое не идет в голову.

Comment: файл весит 365 кб

Comment: FileSize(f) показывает 186860

Comment: хм,если уменьшить BlockRead(f, AByte, 2); , то все норм

Comment: Все таки лучше Filemode было использовать. Reset(f,2) - это немного другое, по-моему.

Comment: если сделать FileMode := 2;
  ReSet(f); , то даже 1 байт не читает BlockRead(f, AByte, 1); дает ошибку, а при  Reset(f, 2); первые 5 байт читает нормально BlockRead(f, AByte, 5); ... не пойму чет ничего

Comment: А f файл какого типа? file of byte? или просто file? если использовать file of byte, то BlockRead(f, AByte, 17); должно работать. Там AV вылетает или другая ошибка?

Comment: был тип file , изменил на file of byte и все стало норм!! спасибо большое !1

Comment: кстати, а если ,к примеру,  я считываю 7 байтов, а записываю обратно 8 , то первые 7 заменятся, а 8 добавится после ?

Comment: Заменятся байты, которые в файле. Тупо перепишутся 8 байт. Чтобы в конец файла добавить нужно seek(f, filepos(f)) сделать. Короче пишется туда, где файловый указатель стоит. столько сколько указал. Чтение вообще не при чем. seek - перемещает указатель blockwrite пишет указанное число байт